# Python Kivy : How to call a function in a template

Tags: python, kivy

I use a ListAdapter with a template.

```
    o__dico_medoc = self.p__database.GetAllMedoc()
    data_items = []
    for key, value in o__dico_medoc.items():
        data_items.append({'text': '  %s   %s' % (value.get('NAME'), value.get('DOSAGE')),
                           'is_selected': False})

    list_item_args_converter = lambda row_index, obj: {'text': obj['text'],
                                                       'is_selected': obj['is_selected'],
                                                       'size_hint_y': None,
                                                       'height': '50sp'}

    self.list_adapter = ListAdapter(data=data_items,
                                    args_converter=list_item_args_converter,
                                    selection_mode='single',
                                    allow_empty_selection=True,
                                    template='MedocListItem')

    self.adapter_list_medoc.adapter = self.list_adapter
```

And the template is :

```
[MedocListItem@SelectableView+BoxLayout]:
    size_hint_y: ctx.size_hint_y
    size_hint_y: ctx.size_hint_y
    height: ctx.height
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    ListItemButton:
        size_hint: (.9, 1)
        text_size: self.size
        text: ctx.text
        is_selected: ctx.is_selected
    ListItemButton:
        size_hint: (.1, 1)
        text: "INFO"
        on_press: DisplayInformation(ctx.text)
```

In the second ListItemButton how to can call the on_press function. I know the template is not a class, so the function is not defined. But how to do ?

The system of ListAdpater is very difficult to learn it.

Comment: Templates are deprecated, you should use either a normal python class or a dynamic class.

Comment: I have find another solution, in the template I have change the ListItemButton by a CustomButton and I have build a class `class CustomInfoButton(SelectableView,Button):` and now I can declare the function `DisplayInformation(self, p__text)`